Vuex module does not provide an export named createStore
Iam importing vuex from cdn, following the instructions. I do this:
import { createStore } from "https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js";
and I get an error in the console that the requested module does not provide an export named createStore. But this is literally what the documentation says to do.
I tried without the import statement, just assuming that createStore would be in the global namespace given a cdn install. That didn't work either, got an error that it isn't defined.
What am I doing wrong?
Edit: I checked the imported file from Vuex and it definitely does not contain the export keyword.

What is your setup for vue project? This is the thing that's responsible for how it works.
"But this is literally what the documentation says to do" - where exactly?

CDN should normally be a script tag in your index.html.  Then you can do const { createStore } = Vuex. the CDN link as you see does not export anything but instead creates global Vuex object.

@yoduh thanks, this was helpful and removed the error. Still battling other issues but I will post a new question with more details to get to the bottom of that. Thanks again.
